# How get channel object from spring cloud stream in my test

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection, spring-cloud-stream, spring-messaging

I had defined a TestChannel Interface bellow

```
public interface TestChannel {
    String CHANNEL_NAME = "test.channel";

    @Input(value = CHANNEL_NAME)
    SubscribableChannel channel();
}
```

And i try to autowired this channel in test.

```
@SpringBootTest
public class TestChannelHandlerTest extends BaseTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestChannel testChannel;

    @Test
    public void someTest() {
    ...
    }
}
```

But `TestChannel` bean in not found. My question is: how can i autowired any channels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `@Qualifier("test.channel")` to the `@Autowired`.

It wouldn't be needed if the name was `testChannel`.

Answer (score 0):

you also need @EnableBinding(TestChannel.class) somewhere.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but the link of the tested channel i defined in tested class